# interactive pop gesture creating black screen (iOS)

Tags: ios

Some reason when I use the following to swipe back, it causes the screen to be black while I am dragging the view controller:

`self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self`

[image]

Here is a youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GH-C_szmT9Y&feature=youtu.be) to the video of the black screen occurring

I also set the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` appropriately

Why is this happening?

//EDIT:  I am using ECSlidingViewController.  This tends to happen when using pan gesture then using swipe back gesture after.

Comment: Could you provide a code example to reproduce this problem?

Comment: This is exactly my issue: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue was completely related to the library I was using (ECSlidingViewController). The layers were getting messed up when using pan gesture.  I implemeted this fix and it worked

[Link here](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/pull/447/commits/56e0540d5810cc58de5a22b3db3e2e1770f55029)

Comment: Dear Josh I have this issue in react native projects. Would you please explain the cause so I can fix it in my source

Comment: cant help unfortunately, this was native ios